# How to transfer big-sized video files from Google Glass, to be viewed few minutes after the capture?

Tags: google-glass

I have to transfer large-sized video file from glass to a server or on a local computer, just after capture (~400Mb), to be viewed as quick as possible on the target device.

I tried to use the mirror API to get the video but the upload time to google platform is really high (more than one hour for a 10-minutes video length). 
I also tried to make an app to capture video and send it over the wifi, but it took about 3 minutes for 18Mb (So, more than one hour for 400Mb). 
We also studied the android Wi-fi P2P solution, but it seems not available on Glass at this time. 
And I tried to launch Droid NAS or AirDroid application to access Glass file system over the air. Application installation is OK, but I can't run them.

Has someone any solution/recommendation ?

Thanks in advance,

Julian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're willing to do it to a local computer, you can just plug Glass into the local machine and transfer the file. Glass is treated as a Camera device, and most PCs and Macs have software that will let you transfer the videos directly over.

Comment: Yes I agree. I think my problem is the network limit, not the size of files. I hope to see Wi-fi P2P coming in next versions. Thank you !